# Help with a question about $\liminf \limits_{n \to \infty } \int_X {{f_n}\,d\mu } $ and $\int_X {\liminf \limits_{n \to \infty } {f_n}\,d\mu } $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is

> Let $(X, \cal M, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and fix $E\in \cal M$. For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ define the function $f_n:(X, \cal M) \to \Bbb{R}$ given by 
>   $$
> {f_n}(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
> {{\chi _E}(x)}&{n{\rm{ \space is \space odd}}}\\
> {1 - {\chi _E}(x)}&{n{\rm{ \space is \space even}}}
> \end{array}} \right.
> $$ 
>   for each $x\in X$.
>
> Compute $\int_X {\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty } } {f_n}\,d\mu $ and $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_X {{f_n}\,d\mu }$.

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but it looks that $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty } {f_n} = 0$?

So $\int_X \liminf\limits_{n \to \infty}  {f_n}\,d\mu  = 0$ ? 
And $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_X {{f_n}\,d\mu }  = \min \{ \mu (E),\mu (X\setminus E)\} $?

I strongly doubt my judgment but I could not see where I go wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems correct.

By $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty } {f_n} = 0$ you easily deduce that $\int_X \liminf\limits_{n \to \infty}  {f_n}\,d\mu  = 0$, as you said.

And, if $n_k$ denotes the subsequence for odd $n$'s , we have
$$
\int_X {f_{n_k}}\,d\mu=\mu(E)
$$ 
for every $k$ and similarly, denoting by $n_j$ the subsequence of even indices,
$$
\int_X {f_{n_k}}\,d\mu=\mu(X\setminus E),
$$ 
for every $j$.
From this you get your answer $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty } \int_X {{f_n}\,d\mu }  = \min \{ \mu (E),\mu (X\setminus E)\} $.